# ActiveRecord query with between dates and has first attribute value

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Ruby on Rails 3.2

**STEPS**

1) Get every User

2) **If there are Users with the same reseller_id value, only take the First User.**

3) Take Users between dates

4) Count

Example:

```
h=User.all.select(:reseller_id).first
h.where(created_at: '2014-01-01'..'2014-03-31')
h.count
```

**NOTE**

I need to check all User s for being the first with the reseller_id. Then check between the dates.

Comment: do you mean like this ? `User.where(created_at: '2014-01-01'..'2014-03-31').first`

Comment: @anonymousxxx No, that would only give the first record. There will be hundreds between the dates

Comment: `User.select(:reseller_id).where(created_at: '2014-01-01'..'2014-03-31').uniq` ?

Comment: @Pavan this returned nil. :/

Comment: @anonymousxxx Yours works well enough. It returns the reseller_id per User. I just assigned it and did count. Please post as answer. If you can make it first not uniq

Comment: Is there what you want  `User.count(:all, :group => :reseller_id, :condition => "created_at >= '2014-01-01' AND created_at <= '2014-03-31'")` ?

Comment: @anonymousxxx The problem there is if a user was created last week it will catch it

Comment: Sorry, I mean  `User.count(:all, :group => :reseller_id, :conditions => { :created_at => '2014-05-01'..'2014-05-31'})`

Comment: @anonymousxxx This give me a bunch of groups. Also, it doesn't check all Users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go through all User records and grab only the first record with the same value of an attribute...

This will only grab a single record per unique value in a certain field for Users (certain field here being `reseller_id`)

```
h=User.select('DISTINCT reseller_id')
```

This grabs the records I want between dates.

```
t=h.where(created_at: '2014-01-01'..'2014-04-01')
```

Then counts them.

```
t.count
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a couple of things. You need to look at the sql generated by that where.

```
> User.where(created_at: '2014-01-01'..'2014-03-31').to_sql
 => "SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE (`users`.`created_at` BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-03-31')"
```

So, what you want is

```
User.where(created_at: '2014-01-01'..'2014-03-31', reseller_id: <somevalue>).first
```

And maybe you'll also want an order? That can be added before `.first`

I'm **updating** this answer based on the comments below.

First, you get the reseller_id that you want:

```
reseller_id = User.where(created_at: '2014-01-01'..'2014-03-31').where("reseller_id is not null").select(:reseller_id).first
```

Then, run a second query:

```
users = User.where(created_at: '2014-01-01'..'2014-04-01', reseller_id: reseller_id)
```

And you should be golden.

Comment: But the reseller_id value can be anything. I want the first User with the any reseller_id

Comment: `User.where(created_at: '2014-01-01'..'2014-03-31', fullname: 'evan').where("reseller_id IS NOT NULL").first`

You can just string together where clauses using active record and raw sql.

Comment: .first will return only the first record. I want all the records but the first User with the reseller_id

Comment: Ah! Just do this as two queries?

first_id =  User.where(created_at: '2014-01-01'..'2014-03-31').where("reseller_id is not null").pluck(:reseller_id);


User.where(created_at: '2014-01-01'..'2014-03-31', reseller_id: first_id)

Comment: Seems to work, just wierd it is giving same results as User.select(:reseller_id).where(created_at: '2014-01-01'..'2014-03-31').uniq

Comment: `.uniq` loads them all into memory. Mine just grabs the first value from the db, so it'll have a slight performance gain

Comment: I have discovered it is not grabbing the first User with the reseller_id because the Users were created at any time. It is only looking in the date range. I need to check for first User with the reseller_id first, then check if it was created between the dates

Comment: Also, pluck is grabbing more than one. I just want the first.

Comment: .select(:reseller_id).first

Comment: I'm failing to understand where the .select(:reseller_id).first should be implemented in your answer.